# azure-android notification hub valid documentation

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am having problems with the implementation of the notification hub in azure-android. I've tried various methods available on the internet, but I still have not managed to make it. There are comments in the articles that I read stating that the article is out of date.
is there someone who knows valid articles related to the notification hub azure-android ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-android-get-started-push/) about adding Google Cloud Messaging to your azure app? It was posted in October 2014, it should be up to date.

Also there is [an example](https://github.com/YoungjaeKim/zumo_android_sample) from GitHub.